# When is the hypothesis framed in descriptive research?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

In descriptive research is it necessary to frame hypothesis? Do all the quantitative research have hypothesis? kindly assist me with this problem by providing me the link of some research paper or books that support the prove.